# How to stop removing document having embedded document gets the original document from another collection removed as well?

Tags: mongodb, doctrine

I have Notification and NotificationQueue. NotificationQueue has a Notification as an embedded document. Removing a NotificationQueue causes the original Notification to be removed as well. How to stop the original Notification from being removed?

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert all your NotificationQueue documents to hold Notification ids instead of embedded notifications. its safer and it loads faster when you query them.